# `pnpm i` is not creating `node_modules` folder

Tags: pnpm

`pnpm i` is not creating `node_modules` folder.

pnpm completes successfully, but no `node_modules` folder is created.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if there is a package.json with at least one dependency then pnpm should create a node_modules directory (unless you run it with the `--lockfile-only` flag).

Comment: I agree, but it doesn’t work

Comment: From your terse description it doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. Is pnpm printing any output? If yes, share it. Also run `pnpm install --reporter=ndjson` and share the more verbose output.

Comment: I was concerned this might happen – I’m unable to repro the issue

Comment: Please include an example package.json related to the issue you are finding. -1 incomplete question

Answer (score 0):

Check if your package.json has dependencies and dev dependencies. That was the issue for me.

Comment: You mean if it doesn’t have both it won’t create node_modules? I usually only have devDeps

Comment: what would that imply? I have "jest" in devDependencies, but neither installing with or without "--save-dev" help in creating either the "package-lock.json" file or the "node_modules" folder